# Resolving DLL paths when running Unit Tests from VS IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, dll, ide

Product: VisualStudio 2012 and its Testing infrastructure

I have a solution (MySolution) with one C++ DLL project (MyClassLib.dll) and one Unit Test project (TestMyClassLib.dll)

When I build the solution with the debug configuration, all the results get published to MySolution\Debug

However, when I then try to run my debugging tests (Test > Debug > All Tests) or (Test > Run > All Tests) the DLL MyClassLib.dll cannot be resolved.

My assumption is that, when the unit test infrastructure runs, the working directory is the unit test's project directory.

I tried setting the Working Directory for the TestMyClassLib project to the location where all my DLLs get published (MySolution\Debug) but that doesn't seem to set the working directory for where the test infrastructure runs.

What is a *simple* (not adding an extra copy) and *elegant* (not changing my PATH) solution to this problem? Is there not a "working directory" setting that I can set for the Unit Test infrastructure when running from the IDE?

I'd like to see the default be the $(OutDir) rather than the $(ProjectDir) or whatever it is using instead. That would make the default behavior be consistent for the end-to-end IDE experience.

Comment: Have you tried declaring one DLL as dependency of the other to VS?